# The use of OR in interrogative sentences

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conjunctions

> Is Indonesia a developing country or an underdeveloped country?

Or

> Is Indonesia a developing or an underdeveloped country?

I understand that "or" is either inclusive or exclusive.

Is there a rule that I am missing.
Are both these statements grammatically correct?

Comment: One doesn't usually repeat the article in the second form, it's usually _a developing or underdeveloped country_. But both are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at issue:

1. Because all countries are *developing* in some sense, using either/or to compare *developing* and *underdeveloped* is illogical.
2. When using **or,** the second phrase can be shortened considerably as long as meaning is not lost:
   "Is Indonesia a developing country or not?"

Answer (score 0):

*Developing* and *underdeveloped* are not mutually exclusive, so it is not clear whether the *or* is to be understood as inclusive or exclusive, regardless of whether or not the sentences are *grammatically* correct.

We don't hear *underdeveloped* so much nowadays - it might be considered rather derogatory. As @Gary's Student points out, most countries are developing to some extent, so *developing* would normally be used to describe countries that are developing at a faster rate than the richer industrial countries, i.e. most of those that used to be called *underdeveloped*.